# how select the greatest value to the smallest in the database mysql

Tags: mysql

How select the greatest value to the smallest in the database mysql?

This is my code :

```
$query1 = "SELECT MAX(total_view) FROM tb_data WHERE display = '1' GROUP BY total_view" or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query($query1);
$resnum = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($resnum == "")
{ echo '<div>data not found</div>';}
else
{
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)):
........
endwhile;
}
```

I've tried many times but always failed. I want to find data from db,

```
id  name  total_view display
1   abc      50        1  
2   bcd      80        1
3   ccc      20        1
4   ggg      90        1
```

like this:

```
id  name  total_view display
4   ggg      90        1
2   bcd      80        1
1   abc      50        1
3   ccc      20        1
```

Someone know how fix this?

Comment: Please explore the usage of `ORDER BY` in sql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(total_view) as maxview FROM tb_data 
                    WHERE display = '1' 
                    GROUP BY name ORDER BY maxview DESC")or die(mysql_error());
$resnum = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($resnum == 0)
{ echo '<div>data not found</div>';}
else
{
 while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)):
       echo $result['maxview'];
 .......
```

here some notes on your code:

**1-** add ORDER BY

**2-** you should group by name

**3-** dont make or die after string , but after mysql_query query.

**4-** you should switch to MYSQLI or PDO instead pf mysql

**5-** you should compare with the integer 0 not empty string in if statment

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah Ok i think you didnt know how to echo result , try that updated code.

Comment: thanks your code correctly work and give a result, but there seems to be an error also happened to the original data type varchar total_view I change to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your query need to use `Order By` like

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_data WHERE display = '1' ORDER BY total_view DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` is your buddy in that case.

```
$query1 = "SELECT MAX(total_view) FROM tb_data WHERE display = '1' GROUP BY total_view ORDER BY total_view DESC" or die(mysql_error());
```

//Untested, but should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `group by` clause nor a `max` function as you want all the records from the table. Just use `order by` as

```
SELECT id, name, total_view, display FROM Table1 
WHERE display = '1' 
ORDER BY total_view DESC
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5298/4)